# Replace string in brackets in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have string with brackets:

```
Dim A as String = "Example (example1)"
```

I want to replace string in brackets with another string so I should get for example...

```
A = "Example (example2)"
```

Comment: Maybe you want read up on string methods like Replace, Remove, Substring. 
You will end up having to create a new string, unless you want to modify the original string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Regex.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input As String = "Example (example1)"
Dim replacement As String = "example2"
Dim expression As New Regex(\(.*\))
Dim result As String = expression.Replace(input, replacement)
```

That pattern will match anything in-between two parenthesis including other parenthesis (greedy). Adjust `expression` to suit your need.

Comment: a regex was one of the options I suggested below; I just didn't want to bother creating an example.  +1 on your example: very good :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to do string replacement by having a token replaced by the actual string?

If so, then can you just do this with [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx)...

```
Dim myString as String = "example2"
Dim A as String = String.Format("Example ({0})", myString)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you not know what `myString` will be, meaning it will be an input from a user?  `myString` can be set in a number of ways.  Please elaborate and I'll update my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a simple "Replace" in a loop.  Here's a list of VB.Net string functions:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx

An arguably *better* way would be to use the VB.Net "regex.replace":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx