# Regex - replacing a string between parentheses

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've been digging around on here for the last hour or two, including all the possible duplicates that posting this has flagged. I have got absolutely nowhere.

I'm simply trying to replace a string in a filename *within* the parentheses, i.e.

`2014 01 26 0000 CFR (Float).DAT` should return `2014 01 26 0000 CFR (Tagname).DAT`

and

`2014 01 26 0000 CFR (String).DAT` should also return `2014 01 26 0000 CFR (Tagname).DAT`

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357504/replace-string-in-brackets-in-vb-net) question, I am using:

```
Dim r As New Regex("\(.*\)")
Dim result As String = r.Replace(logfilename, "Tagname")
```

But this returns `2014 01 26 0000 CFR Tagname.DAT` - I need to retain the parentheses.

I realise I could use this and simply do:

```
Dim result As String = r.Replace(logfilename, "(Tagname)")
```

but that's not the point.

Regex is (obviously) not my strong point.

**Update:**

After [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) put the inevitable seeds of doubt in my mind, I finally went with this:

```
Dim tagfilename As String = ""
If Regex.Match(logfilename, "\(Float\)\.").Success Then
    tagfilename = Regex.Replace(logfilename, "\(Float\)\.", "(Tagname).")
End If
If Regex.Match(logfilename, "\(String\)\.").Success Then
    tagfilename = Regex.Replace(logfilename, "\(String\)\.", "(Tagname).")
End If
```

Comment: Actually, that is a good solution, regardless of what 'point' you speak of.

Comment: @aleph_null: That's just me - I just thought it was a bit silly removing the parentheses, only to add them again after. Still, whatever works!

Comment: Probably should go with `\([^()]*\)` as the regex, `(Tagnamee)` as replacement. With the `.*` notation, you could match other `()`'s in the string.

Comment: @sln: Sorry, you'll have to explain the difference between those two expressions to me then. The files I'm processing are generated by another application and there should(!) only ever be one set of parentheses in the filename - that said, knowing the vendor I should probably never say never.

Comment: If thats all, then it should be fine.

Comment: @sln: Ok, I guess I'll only worry about it if and when the vendor changes the file name format. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use what you have `Dim result As String = r.Replace(logfilename, "(Tagname)")`.

You can use look-ahead and look-behind, but it unnecessarily makes the regex complicated:

```
Dim r As New Regex("(?<=\().*(?=\))")
```

Comment: I'll go with the quick 'n' dirty then, no point in complicating things unnecessarily. Thanks for the advice.